# Calculate the percentage using Over Partition By

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I would like to added a calculate column that calculate the unique order numbers for 'apple' in percentage for each store. For example, store A has 4 orders in total, but 2 of them have the same order number. Therefore, the percentage of the 'apple' order for `store a` is 2/3 = 67%

```
   store       order no    product      
     a           abc         apple        
     a           bde         orange
     a           abc         apple
     a           feg         apple
     b           lmn         apple         
     b           mno         pear
     c           tsx         apple
```

The desire output should be like this:

```
   store       product     
     c          100%  
     a          67%   
     b          50%
```

This is the query I tried:

```
count(distinct(case when product = 'apple' then order no end) 
 /
count(distinct order no) over(partition by store)
```

For some reason the query above doesn't return the right percentage for each store.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT store,
       SUM(product = 'apple') / COUNT(*) 
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT *
       FROM table ) t
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Window functions not needed.